How to increase the access token expire time for azure SSO login
Tried below method:
Sign in to the Azure portal.
Navigate to the Azure Active Directory.
Click on App registrations and select the application for which you want to increase the access token expiration time.
Select the “Manifest” tab.
In the manifest editor, search for the “accessToken” property and update the value of the “accessTokenLifetime” property in seconds.
Save the changes and close the manifest editor.
After these steps, the access token expiration time for the selected application will be increased.
In manifest added below code:
"accessToken": {   
    "accessTokenType": "jwt",  
    "value": null,  
    "userFlowType": "UserFlows/SignUpSignIn",  
    "userFlowVersion": 1,  
    "accessTokenLifetime": 3600,  
    "includeEmailInIdToken": false,  
    "scope": [  
      "openid",  
      "profile",  
      "email",  
      "offline_access"  
    ]  
  }

error:

Failed to update XXXXXX application. Error detail: A value without a
type name was found and no expected type is available. When the model
is specified, each value in the payload must have a type which can be
either specified in the payload, explicitly by the caller or
implicitly inferred from the parent value. [/axcDaTlIjTKt3x3K7n5ps]


How did you know about these settings for manifest? When I create a new registration, I don't see "accessToken" section.

To increase the token lifetime policy, you must create a policy like below:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies
Content-type: application/json

{
    "definition": [
        "{\"TokenLifetimePolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"AccessTokenLifetime\":\"8:00:00\"}}"
    ],
    "displayName": "Contoso token lifetime policy",
    "isOrganizationDefault": true
}


Assign this policy to the application:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/AppObjID/tokenLifetimePolicies/$ref
Content-Type: application/json

{
 "@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies/PolicyID"
}


I generated token for the application and the token lifetime is 10 hrs:

You can set the token lifetime in the particular user flow like below:

References:
Configure tokens - Azure Active Directory B2C | Microsoft
Create tokenLifetimePolicy - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft 
